# I want to replace last / by ,

Tags: perl

I want to replace this:

```
a/b/c|d,385|386|387|388|389|390|391|392|393|394|395|396|397|398|399|400/0.162,214|229|254|255|270|272|276|287|346|356|361|362|365|366|367|369/0.18,improve/11.11,
```

With:

```
a/b/c|d,385|386|387|388|389|390|391|392|393|394|395|396|397|398|399|400/0.162,214|229|254|255|270|272|276|287|346|356|361|362|365|366|367|369/0.18,improve,11.11,
```

With this sed command:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)\//\1,/'
```

This works in Unix. I tried to use this with system in Perl code, but it doesnt work. I request a solution using sed in Perl for the same.

Comment: ‘*using sed in Perl*’ Why on earth would you do that?!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the code you claim works doesn't.

```
$ printf 'a/b/c\n' | sed 's/(.*)//\1,/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
```

It should be

```
$ printf 'a/b/c\n' | sed 's/\(.*\)\//\1,/'
a/b,c
```

You're asking how to execute this command from Perl. You can use the following:

```
 system('sed', '-i', '/\\(.*\\)\\//\\1,/', '--', $qfn)
```

Note that you can quite easily do the same task in Perl itself.

```
local @ARGV = $qfn;
local $^I = '';
while (<>) {
    s{^.*\K/}{,};
    print;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ikegami,I still see an issue. sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'.

Comment: I used system "sed -i 's/\(.*\)\//\1,/' $a" ;

Comment: That's not the solution I posted

Comment: I just used the same thing except that I used it in system() in a perl code

Comment: I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do this in `sed`:

```
echo "365|366|367|369/0.18,improve/11.11," | sed 's/^\(.*\)\/\(.*\)$/\1,\2/'

      365|366|367|369/0.18,improve,11.11,
```

The regex pattern used is:

```
^\(.*\)\/\(.*\)$
```

This says to match and capture everything up until the *last* forward slash.  Then, also match and capture everything *after* the last forward slash.  Finally replace with the first two capture groups, but now separated by a comma.

Notes:

- forward slash `/` needs to be escaped by a backslash, to distinguish it from being the pattern delimiter
- parentheses in the capture groups also need to be escaped with backslash

Comment: Hi Tim, Still have an issue .sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command

Comment: I used this --> sed -i 's/^\(.*\)\/\(.*\)$/\1,\2/'

Comment: Use my answer as a starting point, and go from there.  It was working, at least in a Bash demo.

Comment: Thanks Tim, thats working in bash. If I use the same in a perl code with system(), it does not.